# Iterating through array causing IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I keep receiving a "IndexError: list index out of range" error but I'm unsure why that would be the case

```
def missingNumber(nums):
   sorted_nums = sorted(nums)
   for num in sorted_nums[1:]:
      print(num,sorted_nums[num]-1)
      if ((sorted_nums[num] - sorted_nums[num]-1) > 1):
         res = (num + num + 1)/2
   return res
print(missingNumber([3,0,1]))
```

Comment: You probably meant `sorted_nums[num - 1]`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Still receive the same error

Comment: I hadn't read all of your code.... You are also using the numbers in the list, over which you iterate,  as indexes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are using a `list` not an array. When you iterate over a container in Python, it generally returns the values it contains. So for a list `a = [8, 9, 10]` then `for x in a: print(x)` will print `8`, `9`, and `10`. So if you try to do `a[x]` any of those iterations, it will throw an index error. You probably just want `num - 1` instead of `sorted_nums[num]-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: nums = [3,0,1]

```
//sorted_nums = [0,1,3]
//sorted_nums[1:] = [1,3]
for num in sorted_nums[1:]:
  //here num is element not index
  //so sorted_nums[3] is "IndexError: list index out of range"
  print(num,sorted_nums[num]-1)   
  if ((sorted_nums[num] - sorted_nums[num]-1) > 1):
     res = (num + num + 1)/2
return res
```

so do this

```
sorted_nums = [0,1,3]
for num in range(1,len(sorted_nums)):
  print(num,sorted_nums[num]-1)    

  if ((sorted_nums[num] - sorted_nums[num-1]) > 1):  // 1-0 is not greater than 1
     res = (sorted_nums[num] + sorted_nums[num-1])/2
     return res
```

1st iteration

```
 num = 1, sorted_nums[num] = 1,sorted_nums[num-1] =0 
 1-0 is not greater than 1
```

2nd iteration

```
 num = 2, sorted_nums[num] = 3,sorted_nums[num-1] =1 
 3-1 = 2 is greater than 1 
 so res = (3 + 1)/2 = 4/2 = 2
 missing number is 2
```